# How to get Google calendar event attachment using Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have written a Google Apps Script which successfully attaches a Google Sheets document to a newly created Calendar Event. The following code shows how this is achieved:

```js
var eventObj = { 
    summary: eventName,
    start: {dateTime: startDate.toISOString()},
    end: {dateTime: endDate.toISOString()},
    attachments: [{
      'fileUrl': 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=' + fileID,
      'title' : 'Booking Sheet'
    }]
  };
  
  Calendar.Events.insert(eventObj, inStorePartiesCalendarID, {'supportsAttachments': true});
```

This all works perfectly. I am now writing a script to iterate all events over a certain time period, and grab those attached file ID's.

I am able to successfully get the events I am after, but am having trouble accessing the ID of the attached Google Sheet.

The [Calendar API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events) appears to tell me this is possible. This is taken from the documentation:

> [attachments[ ].fileId,   string] : ID of the attached file. Read-only.
>   For Google Drive files, this is the ID of the corresponding Files resource entry in the Drive API.

If anyone could help me put this all together and show me a way to grab the ID of the attached Google Sheet, it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks :)

Ryan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to retrieve file IDs from an event. If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script?

#### Sample script :

```
var inStorePartiesCalendarID = "### calendar ID ###";
var eventId = "### Event ID ###";
var res = Calendar.Events.get(inStorePartiesCalendarID, eventId, {fields: "attachments/fileId"});
var fileIds = res.attachments.map(function(e){return e.fileId});
Logger.log(fileIds)
```

#### Note :

- This sample script supposes that you have already known the event ID. If you need the method for retrieving the event IDs. Please tell me.
- If you want to retrieve the file ID and filename of the attachment file, please use `attachments(fileId,title)` for `fields`.

#### References :

- [Calendar.Events.get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get)
- [fields](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource-representations)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: This works great! It is all running perfectly now - thank you :)

Comment: @Ryan Saffer Welcome. I'm glad your issue was solved.