# Google Apps Script, get event attachments error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am attempting to duplicate all events from one calendar to another, retaining event colors and attachments.
The following is for testing purposes. Works perfectly until I have added some code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49995649/how-to-get-google-calendar-event-attachment-using-apps-script) to get event attachment. Google API apparently activated correctly.

```
function myFunction() {
  var calendarSource = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("somecalendarIDhere@group.calendar.google.com");
  var calendarDestination = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("primary");
  var eventToCopy = calendarSource.getEvents(new Date("July 21, 2009 EST"), new Date("July 22, 2018 EST"));

  for (var i in eventToCopy){
      // line below throws error
      var res = Calendar.Events.get(calendarSource, eventToCopy[i].getId(), {fields: "attachments/fileId"}); // THROWS "not found" error in debugger
      var fileIds = res.attachments.map(function(e){return e.fileId});
      var options = {description:eventToCopy[i].getDescription(), location: eventToCopy[i].getLocation(), attachments:fileIds}; 
      var newEvent = calendarDestination.createEvent(eventToCopy[i].getTitle(), eventToCopy[i].getStartTime(),eventToCopy[i].getEndTime(), options );
      newEvent.setColor(eventToCopy[i].getColor());
}
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

calendarSource is a Calendar Object. Calendar.Events.get is looking for a calendarID.

try:

```
var res = Calendar.Events.get(calendarSource.getId().split('@')[0], eventToCopy[i].getId(), {fields: "attachments/fileId"}); // THROWS "not found" error in debugger
```

Comment: Thanks mate for helping. Same error `"Not Found (line 22, file "Code")Dismiss"......`

Comment: Maybe the event id is wrong, as this is retrieved using gapps builtin method?

Comment: Ok, caught the problem: GAS builtin `getId()` will return eventid with "@google.com" suffix, while API event['id'] will return event id without the suffix. The latter works, however requires  `Calendar.Events.list` to work

Comment: Good catch. I now remember running into the Calendar Id issue on a project from a few years ago.