# How to loop through event IDs in Google Sheets to retrieve attachment Ids?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Using the following answer, I have discovered how to retrieve a Google Calendar attachment ID using an event ID with Google Apps Script and the Calendar API.

I have a list of calendar event IDs in a column on a spreadsheet that I'm looking to loop through and return the event attachment ID in the adjacent column (and skip over any events that do not have attachments). Could anyone please provide assistance?

Code that got me the code to retrieve 1 event attachment ID at a time:

You want to retrieve file IDs from an event. If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script?

```
var inStorePartiesCalendarID = "### calendar ID ###";
var eventId = "### Event ID ###";
var res = Calendar.Events.get(inStorePartiesCalendarID, eventId, {fields: "attachments/fileId"});
var fileIds = res.attachments.map(function(e){return e.fileId});
Logger.log(fileIds)
```

The question that got me the code to retrieve 1 event attachment ID at a time:
[How to get Google calendar event attachment using Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49995649/how-to-get-google-calendar-event-attachment-using-apps-script)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: @Logan How did you get on with your script for Event ids and attachments? Have you resolved it, or are you still looking for some assistance?

Comment: @Tedinoz I can retrieve event IDs but I need to find a way to retrieve attachments from those event IDs

Answer (score 1):

The OP's starting point was code developed by @Tanaike for [How to get Google calendar event attachment using Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49995649/). The resulting code shown here is an enhancement of that code/logic to enable:

-looping through a range of eventID on a sheet,
-counting the number (if any) of fileIDs attached to that event,
-retrieving each of the fileIDs,
-updating the sheet for the number of files, and the respective file IDs.

It's possible to attach up to 25 attachments to an event. This code is dynamic; it will report and display as many attachments as many exist for any given eventID.

> Note:  the eventID is the `id` field NOT the `iCalUID`.

Also, the code relies on having enabled `Calendar API` under "Advanced Google Services" (Script Editor Menu: Resources> Advanced Google Services) as well as on the "Google Calendar API" on the "Google Cloud Platform API Dashboard."

I've left a number of Logger statements in the code should the OP wish/need to identify key values at various stages of the function.

```
function so53877465() {
  // setup the spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("testsheet");

  // get the number of EventIDs in Column A
  var Avals = ss.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: The last row on A = " + Alast);// DEBUG

  //Loop though each event ID
  for (var r = 1; r < Alast; r++) {
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: Aval row " + r + " = " + Avals[r][0]);//DEBUG

    // substitute your own Calendar ID
    var myCalendarID = "<<inset your Calendar ID>>";

    // get the eventID
    var eventId = Avals[r][0];

    // get the Even info
    var response = Calendar.Events.get(myCalendarID, eventId);

    // just focus on the attachments
    var events = response.attachments;

    // setup some variables
    var filecount = 0; //count the number of files in an event
    var filearray = []; // create an array for the file could and fileIDs

    // ccount the number of attachments for this eventID
    for (key in events) {
      filecount++;
    }
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: For row = " + r + ", the file count is " + filecount);//DEBUG

    // push the filecount onto the empty array
    filearray.push(filecount);

    // loop through the fileIDs
    for (i = 0; i < filecount; i++) {
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: i: " + i);// DEBUG

      // get the attachments
      var event = events[i];
      //get the file iD
      var myfileid = event.fileId;
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: The file id: " + myfileid);//DEBUG

      // push the fileid onto the array
      filearray.push(myfileid);
    }

    // adjust the array for 2d
    var values = [
      filearray
    ];

    // define the target range
    var range = sheet.getRange((r + 1), 2, 1, (filecount + 1)); //(row, column, numRows, numColumns)
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the target range is " + range.getA1Notation());//DEBUG

    // update the target range with the array values.
    range.setValues(values);
  }
}
```

---

**BEFORE**
[image: Data sheet - BEFORE]

---

**AFTER**
[image: Data sheet - AFTER]

Comment: this is awesome! thank you fr your help. This is working (almost) perfectly, I'm running into an issue where the scrip will stop in the middle of the list and throws and 'not found' error. Any idea on how to get past this ?

Comment: @Logan "the scrip will stop in the middle of the list and throws a 'not found' error." OK - good example of needing to be more precise. What is the exact error message - what is it that is "not found" - is it this line `var response = Calendar.Events.get(myCalendarID, eventId);` (line 22 in my code)? If so then it's probably an invalid EventID?

Comment: you are correct, the 'Not Found' error references line 22. Its odd as I'm pulling these event IDs directly from the calendar, I wonder if it is the type of event.

Comment: Note: the eventID is the 'id' field **NOT** the `iCalUID`.