# Calendar Events - retrieve Attachment Url

Tags: google-apps-script

Here is a link: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource-representations
On the bottom of you can see:

```
"attachments": [
    {
      "fileUrl": string,
      "title": string,
      "mimeType": string,
      "iconLink": string,
      "fileId": string
```

I have in my Google calendar many events, some with attachments which are pictures.

I want to append all the events with the fileurl to the sheet.

How can I do that?

This is a part of my code:

```
for(var x=0;x<events.length;x++){
    var messages = event.getTitle();
    var idEvent = event.getId();
    var eventStart = event.getStartTime();
    var eventEnd = event.getAllDayEndDate();   
  //  var eventPictureURL = ?????
    sheet.appendRow([messages,idEvent,eventStart]);
  }
```

I want this as the result.

```
sheet.appendRow([messages,idEvent,eventStart], eventPictureURL);
```

Comment: What is the result you are currently getting?

Comment: `CalendarApp` and the Google Calendar REST API are not the exact same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49995649/how-to-get-google-calendar-event-attachment-using-apps-script Check if it works for you

Comment: SIDMISH, that code gives me an error for "Calendar...."

Comment: Haem, I cant find the exact solution so I actually dont have any result.